# PHP Tesseract , text extraction from an image

Tags: php

I have a requirement where i need to extract the content from the images. Now i have been successful in doing that when it comes to extracting the entire content from an image using the below command .

```
 shell_exec("/usr/bin/tesseract inv.jpg invoice -l eng");

$data = file_get_contents('invoice.txt');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

This gives me the entire content. Now i need to know how to go about extracting the data only from a specific portion of an image using the co-ordinates .

Any advice would be helpful .

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using imagemagick to crop the image? Either that or [imagecrop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php).

Comment: i know that's a possibility , but i do not want to crop the image at all. Apparently Tesseract can take the co-ordinates and extract the content from it , which is something i really cannot find anywhere.